# Is this sentence grammatically correct? does x or y

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> **Does** behaviorism **or** cognitivism better explain learning?

how would you phrase it differently

Answer (score 1):

It's fine but awkward.

> Which of behaviorism or cognitivism better explains learning?

or, better still,

> Which [one] better explains learning: behaviorism or cognitivism?

are both less uncomfortable